# One VPC doesn't see another VPC using peering connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have ec2 instance on the one VPC and RDS instance on another VPC.
I created a peering connection like in that guidance http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/working-with-vpc-peering.html#create-vpc-peering-connection

[image]

After that I updated route tables using the next instruction http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/working-with-vpc-peering.html#vpc-peering-routing

There are screens from my aws console:

[image]

and

[image]

The main problem is that EC2 instance not be able connect to RDS but if I use them on a standalone basis they work good.

Comment: check the security groups

Comment: @Vorsprung , I've checked but when I add one group to another  nothing happened

Comment: Do you only have a single route table in each VPC?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, no. I have two route tables at one VPC and one at another.  But I made two route tables similarly.

Comment: Okay, that was my suggestion @discort, that you verify that *all* route tables include the appropriate `pcx-xxxx` route.  Of course, you also need security group rules to allow the traffic.  Are those in place?

Answer (score 0):

Per your ss it doesn't look like they're associated with your subnets. They say `0 subnets` in the `Explicitly associated`... in the SS

This means the subnet your instance is in is *not* associated with that route table and isn't using it, so it's not pushing that traffic through your peer